# Deploy Qt C++11 app on Mac OS with older libstdc++

Tags: macos, deployment, c++11, linker, libstdc++

When I try to deploy my app on another machine, it fails with `dyld`/unresolved symbol errors.  (Qt static release build, btw.)  When I put `libstdc++` in the bundle (along with `libSystem.B` and `libobjc.A`) and run `install_name_tool` appropriately, I get new linker errors, for libraries upon which these libraries depend.  E.g., `libc++.1`.  I'm really  hoping I don't have to manually go through and run `install_name_tool` on every single library and its children.  (Or write my own script, which I don't know how to do.)  Is there a better way?  This pair ([one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6365772/unable-to-run-an-application-compiled-on-os-x-snow-leopard-10-6-7-on-another-m), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6444054/deploy-osx-application-compiled-using-gcc-4-6)) of questions goes after essentially this question but didn't quite get as far as I did and wasn't resolved in any case.

Here is where I'm at with `otool`:

> $otool -L my_app
>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices
>   (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 41.0.0)
>     /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
>   (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 635.21.0)
>     /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>   (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 55148.6.0)
>     /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Carbon
>   (compatibility version 2.0.0, current version 153.0.0)
>     /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
>   (compatibility version 45.0.0, current version 1138.51.0)
>     @executable_path/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current
>   version 1.2.5)    @executable_path//libstdc++.6.dylib
>   (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.17.0)
>     /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current
>   version 1094.0.0)     /opt/local/lib/gcc47/libgcc_s.1.dylib
>   (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
>     @executable_path/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0,
>   current version 159.1.0)  @executable_path/libobjc.A.dylib
>   (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 228.0.0)
>     /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices
>   (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 53.0.0)
>     /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation
>   (compatibility version 300.0.0, current version 833.25.0)

**Edit:** Here's the initial error message I got, which after making the first round of changes disappeared, to be replaced by a similar message  regarding `libc++.1`:

> Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP) Exception Codes:
>   0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000 Crashed Thread:  0
>
> Dyld Error Message:   Symbol not found: __ZNSt8__detail12__prime_listE
>   Referenced from:
>   /Users/nfoley/Downloads/WaveSorter-mac-1.0.1-static/WaveSorter.app/Contents/MacOS/WaveSorter
>   Expected in: /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib

Comment: if your libs depend on `libc++` why are you bundling `libstdc++`? Shouldn't it be one or the other? What are the unresolved symbol errors?

Comment: @JonathanWakely The very first linker error I got complained about incorrect symbols in `libstdc++`.  So I put it in the application directory and changed the path accordingly and got rid of that error, but then got new ones as described.

Comment: @JonathanWakely I've added the error output to the post.

Comment: Ah, so it's the third-party `WaveSorter` lib which needs `libstdc++` not your own libs, that makes more sense.  You should be able to mix libs linked to libstdc++ and libs linked to libc++ as long as you don't pass `std::` objects between them, due to libc++'s nice clean use of inline namespaces. Have you tried just bindling libc++ too and see if that's all that's needed?

Comment: @JonathanWakely `WaveSorter` is my application.  I don't extend the `std` namespace or anything like that in it.  I haven't tried adding in `libc++.1` yet, that seems like the beginning of a regression that should be avoidable.

Comment: Why? How many different standard library implementations do you think you have installed on your system?! :)  It sounds like some of your libs are built with libstdc++ and some with libc++. Either recompile everything to match, or link to both